# diminish-mode not working in .emacs files

Tags: init-file

I've some minor mode that I want to hide so that it wouldn't clutter my mode line in my emacs config. But the problem is, even after I put the (diminish 'minor-mode) lines in my .emacs file, the minor modes aren't hidden in mode line. I've to manually evaluate the diminish-mode lines everytime I restart an emacs session.

What am I doing wrong ? Is there anyway I can fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, you're probably trying to diminish a mode before it's been loaded?

Refer to the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiminishedModes) for an example of using diminish correctly with `eval-after-load`. If you want to address lots of modes, [delight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedModes)'s more compact syntax may appeal.